# Adwhirl in ViewController of ios

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

Can anyone help me in integrating Adwhirl in View Controller instead of adding it in UIWindow or please help me with any sample code related to this....... please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ADWhirl is a UIView. You can add it as a subview to any view controller's root view, or any view. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6214841/objective-c-adwhirl-banner-in-interface-builder/6215033#6215033) post might help you get some idea.